# How can I set alert confirmation window when delete button pressed

Tags: javascript

I want to add confirmation window when someone click on delete button, I'm using this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn_delete").click(function() {
        $("#delete_id").val("y");
        $("#myform").submit();
    });
});
```

It just delete data without confirmation/alert message, anyone help me to sort out my query.

Thanks

Comment: share your html sample also

Comment: <?php if(isset($data['post']['id'])){?>
                                                <button id="btn_delete" type="button" class="unlock-save" style="background:#4b4b4b; color:#cdbf7a;">DELETE</button>
                                            <?php } ?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) dialog to have a confirmation dialog displayed

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn_delete").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (confirm('Do you want to delete')) {
            $("#delete_id").val("y");
            $("#myform").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much dear Arun, it's working absolutely according to my requirement.